# Buoyancy Nonlinear second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Working on equations of motion of an expandable gaz-filled body immersed uderwater, I have reached the following equation :

$$ \beta^{2} z'' - \alpha(z')^{2} + \beta z z'' - z = 0 $$

Could you give me some advices on how to find and analytical solution, if it exists ? If not, do we have one if we forget the drag, that is if :

$$ \beta^{2} z'' + \beta z z'' - z = 0 $$

Ultimately, what is really of interest for me is not really the entire solutions, but rather stability around the solution $z=0$

Comment: The first equation is non-linear due to the $(z')^2$ term. 

Solutions of non-linear equations are in general harder to find (apart from special cases).

Try working on the second equation first since that's simpler. What have you tried? Show your working.

Comment: Maple gives the following solution: $$\int ^{y \left( x \right) }\!{\frac {\beta}{\sqrt {\beta\, \left( 2\,
\alpha\,{\beta}^{2}\ln  \left( {\it \_a}+\beta \right) +\alpha\,{{\it 
\_a}}^{2}-2\,{\it \_a}\,\alpha\,\beta-2\,\ln  \left( {\it \_a}+\beta
 \right) \beta+{\it \_C1}\,\beta+2\,{\it \_a} \right) }}}{d{\it \_a}}-
x-{\it \_C2}=0
$$

Comment: or $$\int ^{y \left( x \right) }\!-{\frac {\beta}{\sqrt {\beta\, \left( 2\,
\alpha\,{\beta}^{2}\ln  \left( {\it \_a}+\beta \right) +\alpha\,{{\it 
\_a}}^{2}-2\,{\it \_a}\,\alpha\,\beta-2\,\ln  \left( {\it \_a}+\beta
 \right) \beta+{\it \_C1}\,\beta+2\,{\it \_a} \right) }}}{d{\it \_a}}-
x-{\it \_C2}=0
$$

Comment: @unseen_rider For the second equation, I arrived to this formula : $ \beta^{2}z^{''}=\frac{z}{1+\frac{z}{\beta}}$, but there is nothing classic I can recognize from this

Comment: **Welcome to the site !!**

Comment: @unseen_rider, the second equation is also nonlinear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing we notice is that the equation doesn't contain the independent variable, so we can immediately lower the order by one.

Introducing:

$$z'=u(z) \\ z''=u' z'=u u'$$

We get:

$$\beta^2 u u' - \alpha u^2 + \beta z u u' - z = 0$$

Collecting the derivative:

$$\beta (\beta+z) u u'-\alpha u^2-z=0$$

Let's introduce yet another function:

$$u^2=v(z) \\ v'=2u u'$$

We get:

$$\frac{1}{2} \beta(\beta+z) v'-\alpha v-z=0$$

This is now a linear inhomogeneous ODE, which is easy to solve.

---

I hope I haven't made any mistakes, but with ODEs it's always easy to check the final solution by direct substitution, so once you find $v(z), u(z)$ and then $z(x)$ from $z'=u(z)$ you can check.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no $x$-dependence, you can reduce the order by one.

Recall $z''=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}(z')^2}{\mathrm{d}z}$ and we get
$$ (\beta^2 + \beta z) \frac{\mathrm{d}(z'^2)}{\mathrm{d}z} - 2\alpha(z')^{2} = 2z $$
Integrating once gives
$$
z'^2 =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha(\beta-2\alpha)} + \frac{2z}{\beta-2\alpha}+ c (z+\beta)^{2\alpha/\beta} & \alpha\neq 0\\
c+\frac{2 z}{\beta} - 2 \log(z+\beta) & \alpha=0
\end{cases}
$$
but I don't think the final integral can be done in closed form.